# Python3: Remove HTML from string, all examples are simple "tag only" removal

Tags: python

Here's a string:

```
Blah Blah Blah <div><div>sometext</div></div>
```

(WHAT I WANT) - what remains after removal of  all HTML, including inner text so that I get:

```
Blah Blah Blah
```

(WHAT I DON'T WANT) All examples I find are only for tags, which does this:

```
 Blah Blah Blah sometext
```

I need anything ever wrapped in HTML tags, to be removed, even if it's pure text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using BeautifulSoup, iterate over all tags and remove them.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
spam = "Blah Blah Blah <div><div>sometext</div></div>"
soup = BeautifulSoup(spam, 'html.parser')
for tag in soup.find_all():
    tag.decompose()

    # or
    # tag.extract()
print(soup)
```

output

```
Blah Blah Blah
```

Answer (score 0):

You should parse your HTML document with [`Beautiful Soup`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/). You can find all `div`s with `soup.find_all('div')`, and then strip them out of your original string using `replace()`.

Example:

```
>>> import bs4
>>> s = 'Blah Blah Blah <div><div>sometext</div></div>'
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(s, 'html.parser')
>>> soup.find_all('div')
[<div><div>sometext</div></div>, <div>sometext</div>]
```

Comment: While good in theory, this assumes the only tag the OP is dealing with is `div`. The could have `span`, `p`, `ul`, etc...